# c++ mex file in matlab

Tags: matlab, external, symbols, mex

I am trying to call a `c++` function from `matlab` using a `mex` file.
While compiling any example mex programs given in the `<root>\extern\examples\mex` folder I get the same error:

```
Creating library C:\USERS\SONY\APPDATA\LOCAL\TEMP\MEX_AA~1\templib.x and object C:\USERS\SONY\APPDATA\LOCAL\TEMP\MEX_AA~1\templib.exp 
arrayProduct.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _fltused 
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _DllMainCRTStartup 
arrayProduct.mexw64 : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

I am using matlab 7.8(2009a) and compiler microsoft visual studio express 2008.

Can someone please help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Did mex -setup complete without error?

Comment: try adding flag `-v` to your `mex` compiling command. This should give you verbose information regarding folders where `mex` searches for shared libraries etc. You might find the error there...